# FreeText in EF2.1: The 'FreeText' method is not supported because the query has switched to client-evaluation.

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to do simple fulltext search:

```
var dbquery = _dbContext.Contents
   .Where(c => EF.Functions.FreeText("Content", "a"));

var result = dbQuery.ToList();
```

but I'm getting:

> InvalidOperationException: The 'FreeText' method is not supported
>   because the query has switched to client-evaluation. Inspect the log
>   to determine which query expressions are triggering client-evaluation.

Maybe it is important to note, that I'm using inheritance:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ForumThread> ForumThreads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ForumPost> ForumPosts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ContentBase> Contents { get; set; }
 }

public abstract class ContentBase
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class GenericContent : ContentBase
{        
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}

public class ForumThread : GenericContent {}

public class ForumPost : ContentBase
{
    public ForumThread Thread { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `EF.Functions.FreeText("Content", "a")` doesn't use anything in `c`. Did you mean `EF.Functions.FreeText(c.Content, "a")`?

Comment: @hvd: you are right, but how did you know? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext) says it should be property name

Comment: Huh. Poor documentation. It just didn't make sense to me, I figured it should be `c.Content` and double-checked with a quick Google search. I would suggest opening an issue on their GitHub Issues page, but it looks like the parameter has already been renamed to `propertyReference`, which is at least a bit better. I think you can post an explanation of why you thought it should be `"Content"`, based on the current documentation, and why it turned out it shouldn't be, as an answer if you like.

Comment: Anyway, I will accept it as answer, if you write one

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way:

```
var dbquery = _dbContext.Contents
    .Where(c => EF.Functions.FreeText(EF.Property<string>(c, "Content"), "a"));
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution?

Comment: Solved the same problem with `EF.Functions.Contains` in my case. No idea why or how, since documentation is nonexistent.